# Google Classroom API References doesn't ask for Description Heading

Tags: google-classroom

I am creating a google classroom using API's. There is a field called Description heading in the Google classroom API reference, but when I create a classroom, it doesn't ask for a Description heading.

Where can I find and change the value of the Description heading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [`Method: courses.create`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create) then you can add from the request body sample:

```
Request body:
     {
          id:
          name:
          room:
          section:
          description:
          descriptionHeading: // add the description heading here
     }
```

> *descriptionHeading* **string**
>
> Optional heading for the description. For example, "Welcome to 10th
>   Grade Biology." **If set**, this field must be a valid UTF-8 string and no
>   longer than 3600 characters.